# Rainbow color for text

Tags: css, firefox

```
.rainbowtext{ background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #f22), color-stop(0.15, #f2f), color-stop(0.3, #22f), color-stop(0.45, #2ff), color-stop(0.6, #2f2),color-stop(0.75, #2f2), color-stop(0.9, #ff2), color-stop(1, #f22) );
background-image: gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #f22), color-stop(0.15, #f2f), color-stop(0.3, #22f), color-stop(0.45, #2ff), color-stop(0.6, #2f2),color-stop(0.75, #2f2), color-stop(0.9, #ff2), color-stop(1, #f22) ); 
color:transparent;
-webkit-background-clip: text;
background-clip: text;
font-weight: bold; }
<p class="rainbowtext">Hello! This should have rainbow coloring.</p>
```

I want to make a text to have rainbow coloring. This code works fine but only with Safari/Chrome, in firefox the text is transparent. I've tried messing around with it with no success. Any help :P?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please add more detail and a complete code example. Thanks.

Comment: Tried adding `-moz-gradient` as well?

Comment: @j08691 How is this unclear? He wants to have a rainbow effects and includes a snippet that only works in Webkit browsers, he wants this to also work in Firefox.

Comment: @user1129884 - If you see the edit history of the post you'll notice the OP added the details I asked for.

Comment: @j08691 I was talking about the first draft. Didn't see the edit untill you mentioned it. The intention was clear from the first draft as well, though perhaps more hidden, still clear enough.

Comment: TL;DR You can't. `-webkit-background-clip: text` is a Webkit specific feature. It is not a standard property/value. According to [the spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-backgrounds-3/#the-background-clip), the accepted values for `background-clip` are `border-box`, `padding-box` and `content-box`.

Comment: @Prost Sunt I edited my answer with a working svg code, it should fit your question now

Answer (score 3):

### Edit2

Found a solution on [Yoksel](http://codepen.io/yoksel)'s [codepen](http://codepen.io/collection/lEHDb/) using SVG that draws a 200x200 pattern with the rainbow gradient, and then is applied to the text as fill.

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg  width="350" height="25">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="rainbowGradient" x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="0%"> <!--20% spreadMethod="repeat"-->
          <stop offset="0%" stop-color="crimson" /><stop offset="10%" stop-color="purple" />
          <stop offset="10%" stop-color="red" /><stop offset="20%" stop-color="crimson" />
          <stop offset="20%" stop-color="orangered" /><stop offset="30%" stop-color="red" />
          <stop offset="30%" stop-color="orange" /><stop offset="40%" stop-color="orangered" />
          <stop offset="40%" stop-color="gold" /><stop offset="50%" stop-color="orange" />
          <stop offset="50%" stop-color="yellowgreen" /><stop offset="60%" stop-color="gold" />
          <stop offset="60%" stop-color="green" /><stop offset="70%" stop-color="yellowgreen" />
          <stop offset="70%" stop-color="steelblue" /><stop offset="80%" stop-color="skyblue" />
          <stop offset="80%" stop-color="mediumpurple" /><stop offset="90%" stop-color="steelblue" />
          <stop offset="90%" stop-color="purple" /><stop offset="100%" stop-color="mediumpurple" />
        </linearGradient>
      
        <pattern id="rainbow" 
                 patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                 width="200" height="200" 
                 viewbox="0 0 200 200">
          <rect width="200" height="200"
                  fill="url(#rainbowGradient)"/>
        </pattern>
      </defs>
  
    <text x="0" y="50%" style="fill: url(#rainbow);">Hello! This has have rainbow coloring.</text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

---

### Edit

Ironically enough I am using ff here, so I misunderstood your question.

This effect that you are using is exclusive to webkit, there is no counterpart on firefox to `-webkit-background-clip: text;`

Comment: yes, this isn't the absolute correct syntax, because there is few parameters, this is why I included the docs

Comment: Yea.. because it would only show the background as gradient. no text clipping

Comment: @ProstSunt As far as I know, the `background-clip: ;` property in firefox does not support the value `text`. Rendering this impossible to do with this method in firefox.

Comment: `while you are asking for gradient LETTERS, my answer is for gradient background` So the answer is totally pointless for the question. Besides, there was never such `-moz-gradient` property in any versions of FF.

Comment: @HashemQolami , RickHitchcock There fixed it c: